# Dimensional analysis with chemistry equations on stack exchange?

Tags: support, mathjax, mhchem

I know we use [Mathjax/mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/).

What I would like to know, is if its possible to cross out units as part of dimensional analysis.

Here is an example of the desirable effect:
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MathJax includes `\cancel{}` and `\bcancel{}`; however, this extension is not loaded by default on Chemistry.SE. It can be manually loaded using `\require{cancel}`.

### Test

`$$\require{cancel}y=\frac{(x+1)\cancel{(x+2)}}{3\cancel{(x+2)}}$$` 
$$\require{cancel}y=\frac{(x+1)\cancel{(x+2)}}{3\cancel{(x+2)}}$$

`$$\require{cancel}m=n\cdot M=2.50\ \mathrm{mol}\times60.05\ \mathrm{g/mol}=150\ \frac{\mathrm{\cancel{mol}\ g}}{\cancel{\mathrm{mol}}}=150\ \mathrm{g}$$`
$$\require{cancel}m=n\cdot M=2.50\ \mathrm{mol}\times60.05\ \mathrm{g/mol}=150\ \frac{\mathrm{\cancel{mol}\ g}}{\cancel{\mathrm{mol}}}=150\ \mathrm{g}$$

Comment: Are there other LaTeX packages &c that can be loaded with that `\require` command?

Comment: Above comment converted to a question, [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-non-default-latex-features-are-available-to-mathjax-via-require?noredirect=1&lq=1).