# What additional formatting features are available to MathJax (possibly via \require{})?

Tags: support, mathjax

In his [answer](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3539/11367) to a question about crossing out units in dimensional analysis, Loong notes that the `\cancel{}` LaTeX command can be enabled in MathJax by using `\require{cancel}` at the start of a MathJax block.

What other commands/features can be enabled in MathJax through the use of `\require{}`, or other similar MathJax-internal commands?

---

[Peter's answer](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-additional-formatting-features-are-available-to-mathjax-possibly-via-requ#3541) points to the [MathJax documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#tex-and-latex-extensions), which lists the additional features available using `\require{}`. Many of these features are sufficiently cool and potentially useful that I want to make them more visible. So, I plan to lay out the available features and examples of their usage in the answers below. For convenience, below is a table of contents—you may want to wait to click these until the page has fully loaded and all of the MathJax has rendered, otherwise the entry you want may "run away" from you:

- [**2-D Reaction Networks** – `\require{AMScd}`](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-additional-formatting-features-are-available-to-mathjax-possibly-via-requ#3543)
- [**Cancellation Lines** – `\require{cancel}`](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-additional-formatting-features-are-available-to-mathjax-possibly-via-requ#3544)
- [**Coloring (CSS-Style)** – `\bbox`](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-additional-formatting-features-are-available-to-mathjax-possibly-via-requ#3638)
- [**Coloring ($\mathrm\LaTeX$-Style)** – `\require{color}`](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-additional-formatting-features-are-available-to-mathjax-possibly-via-requ#3646)
- [**Command Grouping** – `\require{begingroup}`](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-additional-formatting-features-are-available-to-mathjax-possibly-via-requ#3556)
- [**Extensible Arrows** – `\require{extpfeil}`](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-additional-formatting-features-are-available-to-mathjax-possibly-via-requ#3624)
- [**mediawiki-texvc Symbols** – `\require{mediawiki-texvc}`](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-additional-formatting-features-are-available-to-mathjax-possibly-via-requ#3588)
- [**Links and CSS Styling/Formatting** – `\href`, `\style`, `\class`, `\cssId`](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-additional-formatting-features-are-available-to-mathjax-possibly-via-requ#3636)
- [**Overlay/Enclosure Annotations** – `\require{enclose}`](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-additional-formatting-features-are-available-to-mathjax-possibly-via-requ#3563)
- [**Tooltips and Toggleable Math** – `\require{action}`](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-additional-formatting-features-are-available-to-mathjax-possibly-via-requ#3542)
- [**Unicode Characters** – `\unicode`](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-additional-formatting-features-are-available-to-mathjax-possibly-via-requ#3571)

To note, even though [`mhchem` has been enabled on Chem.SE by default](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26/enable-mhchem-mathjax-extension), it is not enabled on many other sites in the Stack Exchange network.  If for some reason you have need of chemical equations somewhere else and `\ce` isn't rendering properly for you, including `\require{mhchem}` should make it work. Per the developer's [comment](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-additional-formatting-features-are-available-to-mathjax-possibly-via-requ?noredirect=1#comment5160_3540) and [chat post](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36253603#36253603), though, beware that sites that do not specifically load the newest `mhchem` will load whatever version is packaged with the current version of MathJax, and therefore some behavior may differ, possibly significantly.

The `amsmath` and `amssymbols` extensions are also enabled by default on Chem.SE. The symbols available by default, as well as those that require activation by [`\require{mediawiki-texvc}`](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-additional-formatting-features-are-available-to-mathjax-possibly-via-requ#3588), can be browsed at the [relevant section of the MathJax documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands). **In particular, if you are interested in using the symbol for Angstrom units**, use `\AA` after supplying [`\require{mediawiki-texvc}`](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-additional-formatting-features-are-available-to-mathjax-possibly-via-requ#3588):

$$
\require{mediawiki-texvc}
\AA
$$

**Finally**, note that using any of these `\require{}` commands will enable the feature set for the *entire webpage* in which they will appear.  This shouldn't be a problem for most the commands laid out here; the primary exception is [`\require{color}`](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-additional-formatting-features-are-available-to-mathjax-possibly-via-requ#3646), which will [interfere with any uses of the default $\mathrm\TeX$ form of `\color{}`](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#color).  As such, [`\bbox`](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-additional-formatting-features-are-available-to-mathjax-possibly-via-requ#3638) is preferred, when possible. There do exist a couple of additional MathJax extensions not listed above that can be loaded with `\require{}`, but I've omitted them here because they will essentially always have significant side-effects beyond just the post in which they're included.

Comment: **Note:**  `bbox`, and `unicode` get loaded automatically when the `\bbox`,  and `\unicode` macros are first used, so no need for `\require` for these.  Similarly, the `html` extension is loaded by the first use of `\href`, `\style`, `\class`, or `\cssId`, so no need for `\require` there, either.  Also, SE's configuration already includes `AMSsymbols`, so no need to include that via `\require`. Finally, note that the `\color` macro from the `color` extension is incompatible with the default `\color` macro, so loading that can cause problems for people used to using the default `\color` macro.

Comment: @DavideCervone Ah, I wondered about some of that auto-load behavior -- I'll edit to incorporate. Also, I dunno why I thought `AMSsymbols` wasn't enabled by default -- on a quick test, you're absolutely right. Will edit there, too. Thanks!

Comment: @DavideCervone I was definitely aware of the change in behavior of `\color`, but it hadn't occurred that this has potential to break other users' posts -- will add a warning for that, too.

Comment: The correct way to write Ångstrom: $\times 10^{-10}\,\pu{m}$.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Oh? The Scandinavian condensed 'AA' isn't appropriate?

Comment: I actually prefer pico-metre and it has the benefit of being more SI than Ångstrom.

Comment: Tbph, I only used pm to date here because I was unable to generate Å *via* `\AA`. I shall now go back and reedit all my relevant posts to read ångströms instead.

Comment: Please note that for the time being, `\require{mhchem}` (used at another SE site) will load the 'legacy' version from MathJax core, while chemistry.SE already uses the improved version 3. So not all input will render identical.

Comment: @DavideCervone I've finished all of the entries for this post -- would you be willing to review them, now that it's complete?

Comment: @hBy2Py, Thanks for putting this page together.  You have done a great job, and made some points that I hadn't thought of myself.  Good work!  I made a few comments, and edited one of the entries to clarify a couple of things, but other than that, I think it is good.

Comment: @DavideCervone Thanks for your assistance in touching it up! It's much better having your input woven into it. I especially appreciate you correcting the post about `\color` -- I've never used $\TeX$ directly, so I had no idea that it was a MathJax thing, not a $\TeX$ thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As described in the MathJax documentation, any of the [core MathJax extensions](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions.html) can be loaded this way (though this can be restricted via the MathJax configuration).

Comment: Great! Is it only those core extensions, listed at that link, that can be used with `\require`? Or are there custom/third-party ones that are available as well?

Comment: Those are the only ones you can call via require.

Comment: Ok -- everything else you have to work up a custom script for, or somesuch?

Comment: Essentially, yes. If you control the MathJax configuration, it's easy to load extensions from our official third party extension repository (and possible to load them from anywhere else too). See the docs for more information.

Comment: Peter, with `\bbox`, is there any way to apply more than one explicitly named CSS style element? Or is it restricted to exactly one? *{time passes}* AH! Semicolons. Never mind!

Comment: @hByPy glad you could work it out. MathJax also offers a non-standard `\style{css}{math}` macro for adding inline-styles to subexpressions, cf. http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#html. Note that styles might not have the same effect on all outputs and that they might be overruled by MathJax's own styles further down the cascade.

Comment: Thanks for noting `\style` (w/caveats) -- I'll add that in!

Comment: Peter, I can get `\style` to work, but when I try to use `\href` in an example it doesn't apply the hyperlink -- it just echoes the `url` and the `math` as regular math input, with no hyperlink generated. Does it generate links for you?

Comment: Also, Peter, please see the Extensible Arrows [answer](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/3624/11367). In particular, (1) can you check whether `\xtofrom` works for you at present; and (2), would it be possible to implement the equilibrium arrows $($`0x21cc`, $\unicode{x21cc})$ into `\extpfeil`?

Comment: @hBy2Py I believe `\href` is disabled for security reasons. `\xtofrom` works but won't be stretchy with the default fonts (for now anyway). For equilibrium, have you tried `\rightleftharpoons`?

Comment: <nod> that works fine for a non-stretching arrow, optionally with `\overset`, but I haven't been able to make it work with `\Newextarrow`.

Comment: Peter, we discovered that applying a border to math with a `\bbox` command causes an hemorrhagic render-splosion in Firefox: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/conversation/bounded-bbox-breaking-bad. Safari (AFAIK) and Chrome still have the alignment troubles noted [below](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3638/11367) but it doesn't munge the rest of the page.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. For the "hemorrhage", could you create an isolated sample that exhibits the problem, say on jsbin or just a snippet that exhibits the problem when pasted to the answer form here? For the "noted below", that's expected behavior right now; MathJax does not know about the 5px border being added via a style element and thus does not take it into account.

Comment: @hBy2Py, in order for an arrow to be stretchable by MathJax, the fonts in use must include the needed glyphs for the three needed pieces: the left end, the middle repeating part, and the right end.  For U+21CC (⇌), you would need to have U+296B (⥫) for the left, U+296C (⥬) for the right, and something like the equal sign (=) for the middle, as long as it has the same spacing between the lines and they are at the same vertical positions as the other two.  Most fonts don't have these characters, and the MathJax TeX fonts don't.  But the STIX fonts do, so if you use those, it will work.

Comment: @hBy2Py, for `\xtofrom`, you would need an arrow with a line over it for the left end, an arrow with a line under it for the right, and something like an equal sign with the right spacing and position to match the other two.  Unfortunately, Unicode doesn't seem to have glyphs for the left and right ends.  So none of the MathJax fonts can make this character stretch.  And for a font to be able to support that, you would probably have to use the Private Use Area to include non-standard glyphs.  We have certainly done that for some needed glyphs, but don't have the ones needed for this array.

Answer (score 11):

## Command Grouping

**Enable with:** `\require{begingroup}`

*Environment:* `\begingroup ... \endgroup`

Quite a few things are possible with MathJax when you set your mind to it. For example you can define new commands with `\newcommand{...}`. In order to preserve default behaviour for the other posts, you might want enclose your post in a group with [`\require{begingroup}`](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#begingroup). $\require{begingroup}$

As a result you can use the following code without destroying our nice site for the next post.

```
$$
\begingroup
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\op{H}\Psi=E\Psi \tag{mathbf}\label{schrödi1}
\endgroup
$$
$$
\begingroup
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\hat{#1}}
\op{H}\Psi=E\Psi \tag{hat}\label{schrödi2}
\endgroup
$$
```

Which gives us:
$$
\begingroup
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\op{H}\Psi=E\Psi \tag{mathbf}\label{schrödi1}
\endgroup
$$
$$
\begingroup
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\hat{#1}}
\op{H}\Psi=E\Psi \tag{hat}\label{schrödi2}
\endgroup
$$

Note that labels added with `\label{}` still have to be unique regardless of grouping: $\eqref{schrödi1}$ and $\eqref{schrödi2}$. Also, note that using `\begingroup .. \endgroup` **does not** contain the effects of loading other packages: once loaded, a package affects the entire page.

Comment: Ah, thanks Mart. I didn't see any particular use cases for `\begingroup`/`\endgroup`, so I was going to leave them out. In particular, I was thinking of them as possibly a way to contain the effects of other `\require` commands, but they don't work for that purpose. Didn't think about `\newcommand`!

Comment: @hBy2Py It is actually one of the most important packages. One ill-placed macro and it can wreck the whole site. I could invert all your fractions and you wouldn't even notice. See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290616/260760

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Well this certainly answers why Loong's post was full of $^\text{troll}$...

Comment: @orthocresol Well, that was a side effect and I only included this to make the changes visible. With a simple `\def\frac#1#2{#2\over#1}`  it would have been barely noticeable.

Comment: Does a loaded extension affect the *entire* page? Or just the rest of the page that loads after that point? Of course, if this is the case, the answer order can vary, so the effects may 'wander' as the post order changes?

Comment: @hBy2Py Yes, only the sections after the definitions are affected. After commands/packages are loaded, it affects everything that is rendered new. If a command/package gets defined/loaded in the last answer and then you edit one of the posts above it, it will temporarily (until a refresh) affect also these posts.

Answer (score 10):

## 2-D Reaction Networks

**Enable with:** `\require{AMScd}`

*Environment:* `\begin{CD} ... \end{CD}`

Construct two-dimensional grids connected with single-headed arrows. Double-headed and double-lined arrows appear not to be supported, unfortunately.  mwchem (`\ce{...}`) is supported, but you have to apply it to each item in the grid, not the entire grid as a single item.

Annotations above/below/beside the arrows are indicated by interleaving them into the codes for the arrows:

Up:      `@AAA`
Down: `@VVV`
Left:    `@<<<`
Right: `@>>>`

Double-lines can be used, but unfortunately without arrowheads:

Vertical:      `@|||`
Horizontal: `@===`

Anywhere a 'non-arrow' needs to be inserted, `@.` can be used.

More information is available in the PDF [here](http://www.jmilne.org/not/Mamscd.pdf).

```
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\ce A         @>k_1>>    \ce B         @.         ~       \\
@Vk_2VV                  @VVk_4V                  @.      \\
\ce C         @>k_3>>    \ce D         @<k_5<<    \ce E   \\
@Ak_7AA                  @VVk_6V                  @.      \\
\ce G         @.         \ce F         @.         ~       \\
\end{CD}
$$
```

$$
\require{AMScd}
~\\
\begin{CD}
\ce A         @>k_1>>    \ce B         @.         ~       \\
@Vk_2VV                  @VVk_4V                  @.      \\
\ce C         @>k_3>>    \ce D         @<k_5<<    \ce E   \\
@Ak_7AA                  @VVk_6V                  @.      \\
\ce G         @.         \ce F         @.         ~       \\
\end{CD}
$$

Answer (score 9):

## Cancellation Lines

**Enable with:** `\require{cancel}`

*Commands:* `\cancel{}`, `\bcancel{}`, `\xcancel{}`, `\cancelto{}`

Overstrike math content with:

- `\cancel`:     A diagonal line rising to the right
- `\bcancel`:   A diagonal line falling to the right
- `\xcancel`:   An 'X'
- `\cancelto`: A single-headed arrow rising to the right, with a value indicated at the end of the arrow

```
$$
\require{cancel}
{\cancel{x} y \over \cancel{x}} = y \\
{x^\bcancel{3} \over \cancel{x^2}} = x \\
\xcancel{0 = 1} \\
\cancelto{\,5}{25 \over 5}
$$
```

$$
\require{cancel}
~\\
{\cancel{x} y \over \cancel{x}} = y \\
{x^\bcancel{3} \over \cancel{x^2}} = x \\
\xcancel{0 = 1} \\
\cancelto{\,5}{25 \over 5}
$$

Answer (score 4):

## Tooltips and Toggleable Math

**Enable with:** `\require{action}`

*Commands:* `\mathtip{math}{tip}` and `\texttip{math}{tip}`

Apply tooltips to math expressions (text shown when the cursor is hovered over the expression). `\mathtip` shows `tip` using math-mode rendering; `\texttip` shows `tip` using text-mode rendering.

```
$$
\require{action}
\texttip{a+b}{This is addition!} \\ ~ \\
\mathtip{\ln{\!\left( e^x \right)}}{=x}
$$
```

$$
\require{action}
~\\
\texttip{a+b}{This is addition!} \\ ~ \\
\mathtip{\ln{\!\left( e^x \right)}}{=x}
$$

---

*Command:* `\toggle{math1}{math2}...\endtoggle`

Create a math object that cycles through different expressions when clicked.

```
$$
\require{action}
\toggle{a}{a+b}{a+b+c}{a+b+c+d}\endtoggle
$$
```

$$
\require{action}
~\\
\toggle{a}{a+b}{a+b+c}{a+b+c+d}\endtoggle
$$

Answer (score 4):

## Overlay/Enclosure Annotations

**Enable with:** `\require{enclose}`  $\require{enclose}$

*Command:* `\enclose{type}[options]{math}`

Apply a MathML 3 enclosure, with optional [text or background color formatting](https://www.w3.org/TR/MathML/chapter3.html#presm.presatt) (see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/MathML/chapter2.html#type.color) for available color descriptors), to `math`.

[Available enclosures include](https://www.w3.org/TR/MathML/chapter3.html#presm.menclose):

- `longdiv` - Long division symbol (it's apparently possible to construct [entire long division problems](https://www.w3.org/TR/MathML/chapter3.html#presm.mlongdiv.ex); I did not take the time to figure out how, though)
   
  `\enclose{longdiv}[mathcolor="red"]{x^2+5}`  $\rightarrow \enclose{longdiv}[mathcolor="red"]{x^2+5}$
- `actuarial` - Symbol from [actuarial notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actuarial_notation) (no particular relevance to chemistry)
   
  `\enclose{actuarial}[mathbackground="#6ad898"]{2x}`  $\rightarrow \enclose{actuarial}[mathbackground="#6ad898"]{2x}$
- `phasorangle` - [Phasor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor) angle symbol (also no particular relevance to chemistry):
   
  `A_1\enclose{phasorangle}{\theta_1}` $\rightarrow A_1\enclose{phasorangle}{\theta_1}$
- `radical` - Root symbol
   
  `^3\enclose{radical}{x^6} = x^2` $\rightarrow~^3\enclose{radical}{x^6} = x^2$
- `box` - Box with hard corners
   
  `\enclose{box}{x = 1 \pm 3}` $\rightarrow \enclose{box}{x = 1 \pm 3}$
- `roundedbox` - Box with rounded corners
   
  `\enclose{roundedbox}{y = {1\over x}}` $\rightarrow \enclose{roundedbox}{y = {1\over x}}$
- `circle` - Ellipse (ironically); may have to include extra horizontal or vertical whitespace to avoid clipping
   
  `\enclose{circle}{f(x)=x^2}` $\rightarrow \enclose{circle}{f(x)=x^2}$
  `\enclose{circle}{~~~~f(x)=x^2\phantom{x^2\over 1}}` $\rightarrow \enclose{circle}{~~~~f(x)=x^2\phantom{x^2\over 1}}$
- `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom` - Line on one side of the math
   
  `\enclose{bottom}{x+y}\cdots\enclose{right}{x\over y}` $\rightarrow\enclose{bottom}{x+y}\cdots\enclose{right}{x\over y}$
- `updiagonalstrike`, `downdiagonalstrike`,
  `verticalstrike`, `horizontalstrike` - Strikethroughs
   
  `\enclose{verticalstrike}{a+b^2\over c+d}`$\rightarrow\enclose{verticalstrike}{a+b^2\over c+d}$
  `\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{a+b^2\over c+d}`$\rightarrow\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{a+b^2\over c+d}$
- `madruwb` - Arabic factorial (renders an approximation on my browser)
   
  `enclose{madruwb}{55}` $\rightarrow\enclose{madruwb}{55}$

**Multiple enclosures can be applied to the same math by passing a space-separated list of enclosures to `\enclose`:**

`\enclose{circle updiagonalstrike horizontalstrike}{y^3 - xy^2}` $\rightarrow\enclose{circle updiagonalstrike horizontalstrike}{y^3 - xy^2}$

At this time (5 Feb 2017) it appears that MathJax does not implement the arrows defined in the MathML specification (`northeastarrow`, `updownarrow`, etc.) except for `updiagonalarrow` (thanks, Davide!):

`\enclose{updiagonalarrow}{3x^2}` $\rightarrow\enclose{updiagonalarrow}{3x^2}$

Comment: As you mention, MathJax does not implement does not implement most of the arrows, only the `updiagonalarrow`.

Answer (score 3):

## Unicode Characters

**Enable with:** `\require{unicode}` *(optional; loads automatically on first use)*

*Command:* `\unicode{#####}` or `\unicode{x####}`

Insert the Unicode character at decimal code point `#####` or hexadecimal code point `x####`.  As usual, proper rendering depends on browser encoding support. There are many resources for Unicode code points around the Internet; searching *"Unicode [thing]"* will frequently point you in the right direction. I discovered [this site](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/) recently, which has a nice categorized listing of an extremely large set of Unicode code points.

### Examples

***Fractions***

From [here](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2150-218F) and [here](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/00A0-00FF):

$
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
\newcommand{graybox}[1]{\bbox[whitesmoke,1px]{\texttt{x#1}}}
~~~~~~~~\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\hline
  \graybox{00bd}   & \graybox{2153}   & \graybox{2154}   &
      \graybox{00bc}   & \graybox{00be} \\
  \unicode{x00bd}  & \unicode{x2153}  & \unicode{x2154}  &
      \unicode{x00bc}  & \unicode{x00be} \\
\hline
  \graybox{2155}   & \graybox{2156}   & \graybox{2157}   &
      \graybox{2158}   & \graybox{2159}   & \graybox{215a} \\
  \unicode{x2155}  & \unicode{x2156}  & \unicode{x2157}  &
      \unicode{x2158}  & \unicode{x2159}  & \unicode{x215a} \\
\hline
  \graybox{2150}   & \graybox{215b}   & \graybox{215c}   &
      \graybox{215d}   & \graybox{215e}   & \graybox{2151}   &
      \graybox{2152} \\
  \unicode{x2150}  & \unicode{x215b}  & \unicode{x215c}  &
      \unicode{x215d}  & \unicode{x215e}  & \unicode{x2151}  &
      \unicode{x2152} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$

***Geometric Shapes***

A few examples from [here](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/25A0-25FF):

$\unicode{x25a0}~~\unicode{x25a1}~~\unicode{x25aa}~~\unicode{x25b7}~~\unicode{x25c1}~~\unicode{x25bd}~~\unicode{x25cb}~~\unicode{x25cf}~~\unicode{x25d0}~~\unicode{x25d7}~~\unicode{x25d8}~~\unicode{x25e2}~~\unicode{x25e8}~~\unicode{x25ea}~~\unicode{x25ed}$

***Punctuation***

Examples from [here](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2000-206F):

$\unicode{x2032}~~\unicode{x2033}~~\unicode{x2034}~~\unicode{x2016}$

And from [here](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/00A0-00FF):

$\unicode{x00a1}~~\unicode{x00bf}~~\unicode{x00a7}~~\unicode{x00ab}~~\unicode{x00bb}~~\unicode{x00b0}~~\unicode{x00a9}~~\unicode{x00ae}$

***Currency Symbols***

Examples from [here](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/20A0-20CF):

$\unicode{x20ac}~~\unicode{x20b9}~~\unicode{x20bd}~~\unicode{xfdfc}$

And from [here](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/00A0-00FF):

$\unicode{x00a2}~~\unicode{x00a3}$

***Arrows***

Examples from [here](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2190-21FF):

$\unicode{x2192}~~\unicode{x2194}~~\unicode{x2197}~~\unicode{x219b}~~\unicode{x219d}~~\unicode{x21a0}~~\unicode{x21a6}~~\unicode{x21aa}~~\unicode{x21ac}~~\unicode{x21b3}~~\unicode{x21b7}~~\unicode{x21c0}~~\unicode{x21c4} \\
\unicode{x21c9}~~\unicode{x21cc}~~\unicode{x21cf}~~\unicode{x21d2}~~\unicode{x21d7}~~\unicode{x21dd}~~\unicode{x21e2}~~\unicode{x21e5}~~\unicode{x21f0}~~\unicode{x21f2}~~\unicode{x21f6}~~\unicode{x21f8}~~\unicode{x21fb}~~\unicode{x21fe}$

***Mathematical Operators/Symbols***

Examples from [here](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/00A0-00FF):

$\unicode{x00d7}~~\unicode{x00f7}~~\unicode{x00b1}$

And from [here](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2000-206F):

$\unicode{x2030}~~\unicode{x2031}$

And from [here](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2200-22FF):

$\unicode{x2200}~~\unicode{x2203}~~\unicode{x2208}~~\unicode{x2213}~~\unicode{x221e}~~\unicode{x2220}~~\unicode{x2227}~~\unicode{x2229}~~\unicode{x2234}~~\unicode{x2243}~~\unicode{x2245}~~\unicode{x2250}~~\unicode{x2273}$

$\endgroup$

Comment: Note that you can specify symbols that are not in the MathJax fonts using `\unicode{}`, and in that case, the glyph will be taken from another font on your system, if there is one that contains the character.  Different systems will have different fonts, and there is no guarantee that everyone will be able to see the character you specified.  Older versions of Windows are particularly bad at locating these characters, even when there is a font that contains them.  Also, the size of the glyph might not match well with the rest of the math.  So use this feature with caution.

Answer (score 3):

## mediawiki-texvc Symbols

**Enable with:** `\require{mediawiki-texvc}`

*Commands: (various)*

As noted in the question, the full set of symbols exposed through the `mediawiki-texvc` extension can be browsed at the [MathJax documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands).  Many of these symbols are (or appear to me to be) one-to-one substitutions for commands already available in MathJax as it is presently configured on Chem.SE.

Included in the table below are a subset of the `mediawiki-texvc` symbols of particular note, either because they are unavailable in the default Chem.SE MathJax or because their `mediawiki-texvc` commands are appreciably shorter and/or clearer. Some are not of particular relevance to chemistry, but are included for the possible benefit of users from (***GASP***) other sites in the SE network.

$
\require{mediawiki-texvc}
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
\def\grbx#1{\bbox[2pt,lightgray,font-size:75%]{\text{#1}}}
\def\smx{--}
$

$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
\hline
{\small\text{Default}}    & \grbx{\spadesuit}    & \grbx{\heartsuit}
                    & \grbx{\diamondsuit}  & \grbx{\clubsuit} \\
{\small\text{mediawiki-texvc}}  & \grbx{\spades}   & \grbx{\hearts}
                          & \grbx{\diamonds} & \grbx{\clubs} \\
{\small\text{Symbol}}  & \spades & \hearts & \diamonds & \clubs \\
\hline
{\small\text{Default}}    & \grbx{\mathbb{C}}    & \grbx{\mathbb{H}}
                    & \grbx{\mathbb{N}}  \\
{\small\text{mediawiki-texvc}}  & \grbx{\C}   & \grbx{\H}
                          & \grbx{\N}  \\
{\small\text{Symbol}}  & \C & \H & \N  \\
{\small\text{Default}}    &  \grbx{\mathbb{Q}} 
                    & \grbx{\mathbb{R}}  & \grbx{\mathbb{Z}}\\
{\small\text{mediawiki-texvc}}   & \grbx{\Q} 
                          & \grbx{\R} & \grbx{\Z} \\
{\small\text{Symbol}}  &  \Q & \R & \Z \\
\hline
{\small\text{Default}}    & \grbx{\rightarrow}  & \grbx{\Rightarrow}
                    & \grbx{\leftrightarrow}  & \grbx{\Leftrightarrow} \\
{\small\text{mediawiki-texvc}}  & \grbx{\rarr}   & \grbx{\Rarr}
                          & \grbx{\lrarr} & \grbx{\Lrarr} \\
{\small\text{Symbol}}  & \rarr & \Rarr & \lrarr & \Lrarr \\
\hline
{\small\text{Default}}    & \smx & \smx & \smx & \smx \\
{\small\text{mediawiki-texvc}}  & \grbx{\coppa}   & \grbx{\Koppa}
                          & \grbx{\sampi} & \grbx{\Sampi} \\
{\small\text{Symbol}}  & \coppa & \Koppa & \sampi & \Sampi \\
{\small\text{Default}}    & \smx & \smx & \grbx{\vartheta} \\
{\small\text{mediawiki-texvc}}  & \grbx{\stigma}   & \grbx{\Stigma}
                          & \grbx{\thetasym}  \\
{\small\text{Symbol}}  & \stigma & \Stigma & \thetasym \\
\hline 
{\small\text{Default}}    & \grbx{\subset} & \grbx{\subseteq} & \grbx{\supset} & \grbx{\supseteq} \\
{\small\text{mediawiki-texvc}}  & \grbx{\sub}   & \grbx{\sube}
                          & \smx & \grbx{\supe}  \\
{\small\text{Symbol}}  & \sub & \sube & \supset & \supe \\
{\small\text{Default}}    & \grbx{\land} & \grbx{\lor}  \\
{\small\text{mediawiki-texvc}}  & \grbx{\and}   & \grbx{\or} \\
{\small\text{Symbol}}  & \and & \or  \\
\hline
{\small\text{Default}}    & \smx & \smx & \smx \\
{\small\text{mediawiki-texvc}}  & \grbx{\AA}   & \grbx{\euro}
                          & \grbx{\textvisiblespace}  \\
{\small\text{Symbol}}  & \AA & \euro & \textvisiblespace \\
{\small\text{Default}}    & \smx & \grbx{\wp}  \\
{\small\text{mediawiki-texvc}}  & \grbx{\vline}   & \grbx{\weierp} \\
{\small\text{Symbol}}  & \vline & \weierp \\
\hline
\end{array}
$

Note that `\vline` and the pipe symbol are not the same:
 
   `\vline` – $\vline$
   `{pipe}` – |

$\endgroup$

Comment: I added some defaults that were missing.  Also, there are a number of macros in the mediawiki-texvc extension that are not listed here.  You can see the complete list in the [source code](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/blob/master/unpacked/extensions/TeX/mediawiki-texvc.js#L31-L124)

Comment: Thanks, @DavideCervone! Yeah, I wasn't trying to make it an exhaustive list -- it's much too extensive for that.

Answer (score 3):

## Coloring ($\rm\LaTeX$ Style)

**Enable with:** `\require{color}`

*Commands:* `\color` (redefinition), `\colorbox`, `\fcolorbox`, `\definecolor`, `\textcolor`

MathJax ships by default with a non-standard implementation of the `\color` command, which applies a case-***insensitive*** [predefined](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors#Predefined_colors) or [`svgnames`](https://www.latextemplates.com/svgnames-colors) color to some math passed to it as an argument:

```
$$
\color{reD}{x+y}+z = \color{bLUe}{m^2} \\
\color{NAVY}{\ce{HCl}}~~\color{MedIUMSEaGREeN}{\ce{NaCl}}
$$
```

$$
{\color{reD}{x+y}}+z = {\color{bLUe}{m^2}} \\
{\color{NAVY}{\ce{HCl}}}~~{\color{MedIUMSEaGREeN}{\ce{NaCl}}}
$$

---

Invoking `\require{color}` loads a much broader set of commands. First, `\color` is overwritten, turning it into a *to-end-of-scope* modifier instead of a pure command that takes the material to be colored as an argument:

```
$$
\require{color}
\color{red}{this} that \\
{or \color{red} this} that
$$
```

$$
\require{color}
\color{red}{this} that \\
{or \color{red} this} that
$$

**This redefinition applies to everything parsed after the `\require` invocation, page-wide.** It thus has the potential to break uses of the default argument-based `\color` in other posts on the page!

---

A command with the argument-coloring behavior, `\textcolor`, is defined:

```
$$
\textcolor{RED}{this} that
$$
```

$$
\textcolor{RED}{this} that
$$

---

The case-***sensitive*** [`dvipsnames`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors#The_68_standard_colors_known_to_dvips) color space is loaded:

```
$$
\textcolor{Apricot}{noodle} \\
{this \color{Thistle} that} other {\color{thistle} wise}
$$
```

$$
\textcolor{Apricot}{noodle} \\
{this \color{Thistle} that} other {\color{thistle} wise}
$$

The difference in color above is due to $\color{Thistle}that$ being colored with [`dvipsnames`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors#The_68_standard_colors_known_to_dvips) case-sensitive "Thistle" but $\color{thistle}wise$ being colored with [`svgnames`](https://www.latextemplates.com/svgnames-colors) case-insensitive "Thistle"/"thistle".

---

New color names can be defined with `\definecolor` in a [variety of ways](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors#Defining_new_colors):

```
$$
\definecolor{mygray2!}{gray}{0.4}
\definecolor{clay}{rgb}{0.8,0.32,0.0}
\definecolor{newBlue21}{RGB}{25,65,180}
~
\textcolor{mygray2!}{12345}~\textcolor{MyGray2!}{67890} \\
\textcolor{clay}{whiplash}~\textcolor{cLAy}{sagebrush} \\
\textcolor{newBlue21}{undertow}~\textcolor{newblue21}{no~good}
$$
```

$$
\definecolor{mygray2!}{gray}{0.4}
\definecolor{clay}{rgb}{0.8,0.32,0.0}
\definecolor{newBlue21}{RGB}{25,65,180}
~
\textcolor{mygray2!}{12345}~\textcolor{MyGray2!}{67890} \\
\textcolor{clay}{whiplash}~\textcolor{cLAy}{sagebrush} \\
\textcolor{newBlue21}{undertow}~\textcolor{newblue21}{no~good}
$$

Color names defined with `\definecolor` are strictly ***case-sensitive***.  It appears that as of this writing the `HTML` and `cmyk` color models described at the above link ***are not available***.

---

Text highlighting and framed text highlighting are provided by `\colorbox` and `\fcolorbox`, respectively. Font coloring is not available as a direct argument to either command, and the contents of both of these commands are set as ***plain text***, not as mathematics or formatted $\rm\LaTeX$. If desired, though, math (and thus full $\rm\LaTeX$ formatting, including text coloration) can be included by surrounding the relevant portions in the typical dollar signs:

```
$$
\colorbox{clay}{$\textcolor{SkyBlue}{\text{This is text.}}$} \\
\fcolorbox{burlywood}{mygray2!}{$\textcolor{Goldenrod}{This~is~\mathbf{framed}~math~text.}$}
$$
```

$$
\colorbox{clay}{$\textcolor{SkyBlue}{\text{This is text.}}$} \\
\fcolorbox{burlywood}{mygray2!}{$\textcolor{Goldenrod}{This~is~\mathbf{framed}~math~text.}$}
$$

Answer (score 2):

## Links and CSS Styling/Formatting

**Enable with:** `\require{html}` *(optional; loads automatically on first use)*

*Commands:* `\href`, `\class`, `\cssId`, `\style`

`\style` allows (nearly) arbitrary CSS formatting to be applied to a math (sub-)expression.  Per usual CSS syntax, separate individual CSS directives by semicolons. [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) has a pretty good CSS tutorial.

```
$$
\style{color: blue}{a+b}+\style{padding: 3pt; background-color: green}{c+d}
$$
```

$$
\style{color: blue}{a+b}+\style{padding: 3pt; background-color: green}{c+d}
$$

Much the same effect can be achieved with the [`\bbox`](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3638/11367) command. As with `\bbox`, the output is only well-behaved if a numerical pixel value is explicitly supplied for `border-width`:

```
$$
\style{border-style: solid; border-width: 5px; padding: 2px}{x^2-3x+2}
$$
```

$$
\style{border-style: solid; border-width: 5px; padding: 2px}{x^2-3x+2}
$$

Nesting `\style` directives can also have dramatic side effects. For example, when drafting this post, I managed to create a math expression that made the webpage page "infinitely long", and totally blank below the CSS-formatted math expression. (For what are hopefully obvious reasons, I removed this expression from the final version of the post....) I hadn't yet discovered the need for explicitly specifying the `border-width` property to avoid misbehavior at that point, though, so it's possible this weirdness stemmed from that same problem.

---

Unfortunately, the remaining three commands supplied by this extension are somewhat useless on Stack Exchange. Per a [comment](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-additional-formatting-features-are-available-to-mathjax-possibly-via-requ#comment5303_3541) by Peter Krautzberger, `\href`, which would allow construction of links within math expressions, appears to be disabled on SE sites for security reasons.  Instead of creating a link, the URL is just echoed into the expression:

`\href{http://www.google.com}{a+b}`

$$\href{http://www.google.com}{a+b}$$

In theory, `\class` would permit formatting arbitrary MathJax expressions with the same styles applied to the 'native' Stack Exchange CSS classes. Considering that 2002 was the last time I worked directly with CSS, I have not had success in extracting class names from the SE `.css` file. (Alternatively, it is possible that `\class` has also been disabled by the SE developers.) If anyone can get this command to work, please feel free to edit instructions into this answer.

`\cssId`, which attaches an `id` attribute to a math (sub-)expression, is of little use on Stack Exchange since to my knowledge post authors don't have the ability to modify the CSS or Javascript running on the site.

Comment: Again, the caveats about using styles that change the size or position of the affected element mentioned in my comments to the `\bbox` command apply here as well.  Note that `\style{border: 5px solid black}{x^2-3x+1}` is easier than giving each of the sub-styles separately.  Also, the width doesn't have to be in pixels, it can be any of the available units, like `em` or `mm`.

Comment: You are correct that `\href` is disabled, though unfortunately it was clumsily handled.  They should have defined it as essentially `\def\href#1#2{#2}` so that the URL (and the extra braces around the math) would be removed, but they did `\def\href{}` instead, so the URL is typeset, as you point out.

Answer (score 1):

## Extensible Arrows

**Enable with:** `\require{extpfeil}`

*Commands:* `\xtwoheadrightarrow`, `\xtwoheadleftarrow`, `\xmapsto`, `\xlongequal`, `\xtofrom`, `\Newextarrow`

Create an arrow with overset content, sized to fit that content.  Five built-in arrows are defined, of which four work properly in my browser: $\require{begingroup}\begingroup\def\rar{\quad\longrightarrow\quad}\require{extpfeil}$

- `\xtwoheadrightarrow{a+b+c}`: $\quad\xtwoheadrightarrow{a+b+c}$
- `\xtwoheadleftarrow{a+b+d+c}`: $\quad\xtwoheadleftarrow{a+b+d+c}$
- `\xmapsto{\text{This is a real, actual sentence.}}`: $\quad\xmapsto{\text{This is a real, actual sentence.}}$
- `\xlongequal{\text{extremely long equals sign}}`: $\quad\xlongequal{\text{extremely long equals sign}}$

I have not been able to get `\xtofrom` to work:

- `\xtofrom{ax^2+bx+c=0}`: $\quad\xtofrom{ax^2+bx+c=0}$

A variety of other extensible arrows can be crafted with this extension, via the `\Newextarrow{\cmd}{lspace,rspace}{unicode-char}` command. Here, `\cmd` is the name of the new command to be defined, `lspace` and `rspace` are integers defining the left and right padding, respectively, for the text to be overset (in units of pixels?), and `unicode-char` is the Unicode code point for the arrow to be typeset in extended form.  To note, `unicode-char` ***must*** be specified in hexadecimal, and ***must*** be prefixed by `0x` (not just `x`). For example:

```
$$
\Newextarrow{\xtriple}{10,10}{0x21db}
\Newextarrow{\xtriplepadded}{50,50}{0x21db}
\xtriple{\text{This is an extended triple arrow!}} \\
\xtriplepadded{\text{This is an extended triple arrow with lots of padding!}}
$$
```

$$
\Newextarrow{\xtriple}{10,10}{0x21db}
\Newextarrow{\xtriplepadded}{50,50}{0x21db}
\xtriple{\text{This is an extended triple arrow!}} \\
\xtriplepadded{\text{This is an extended triple arrow with lots of padding!}}
$$

The following table lays out all of the arrows I have observed to work with `\Newextarrow`; three of these are duplicates of the arrows built into the extension. Conspicuously absent (for now?), unfortunately, is the equilibrium reaction arrow, `0x21cc` $(\unicode{x21cc})$.

$$
\newcommand{graybox}[1]{\bbox[whitesmoke,1px]{\texttt{0x#1}}}
\begin{array}{cccccc}
\hline
\graybox{2190} & \graybox{2192} & \graybox{2194} & \graybox{21d0} & \graybox{21d2} & \graybox{21d4} \\
\unicode{x2190} & \unicode{x2192} & \unicode{x2194} & \unicode{x21d0} & \unicode{x21d2} & \unicode{x21d4} \\
\hline
\graybox{21bc} & \graybox{21c0} & \graybox{294e} & \graybox{21bd} & \graybox{21c1} & \graybox{2950} \\
\unicode{x21bc} & \unicode{x21c0} & \unicode{x294e} & \unicode{x21bd} & \unicode{x21c1} & \unicode{x2950} \\
\hline
\graybox{219e} & \graybox{21a0} & \graybox{21a4} & \graybox{21a6} & \graybox{295a} & \graybox{295b} \\
\unicode{x219e} & \unicode{x21a0} & \unicode{x21a4} & \unicode{x21a6} & \unicode{x295a} & \unicode{x295b} \\
\hline
\graybox{295e} & \graybox{295f} & \graybox{27fd} & \graybox{27fe} & \graybox{21da} & \graybox{21db} \\
\unicode{x295e} & \unicode{x295f} & \unicode{x27fd} & \unicode{x27fe} & \unicode{x21da} & \unicode{x21db} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
$\endgroup$

Comment: you don't actually have to use hexadecimal for the Unicode code point in `\Newextarrow`.  You can use `\Newextarrow{\xtripple}{10,10}{8667}` if you want.  Y9ou are correct that if you *do* use hexadecimal, you must include `0x` to indicate that.

Answer (score 1):

## Coloring (CSS-Style)

**Enable with:** `\require{bbox}` *(optional; loads automatically on first use)*

*Command:* `\bbox[options]{math}`

`\bbox` is somewhat similar to [`\style`](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3636/11367), in that it applies CSS styling to the indicated `math`. The main difference is that it makes two specific assumptions about unqualified CSS directives passed into `options`:

1. An unqualified (case-***insensitive***) [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_colors.asp) or [`svgnames`](https://www.latextemplates.com/svgnames-colors) color is taken as the [`background-color`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp):

`\bbox[cyan]{a+b}` $\quad\rightarrow\quad \bbox[cyan]{a+b}$

2. An unqualified CSS distance measurement is taken as the [`padding`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp):

`\bbox[10px,cyan]{a+b}` $\quad\rightarrow\quad \bbox[10px,cyan]{a+b}$

As shown above, these unqualified CSS directives are separated by a comma.

Arbitrary CSS styling ([w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) has a pretty good tutorial) can also be applied to the `math`, regardless of the presence or absence of the above unqualified directives, by providing a series of semicolon-separated full CSS directives:

`\bbox[lightblue,5px,border-style: solid; border-color:greenyellow; border-width: 4px]{a+b}`

$\rightarrow\quad
\bbox[lightblue,5px,border-style: solid; border-color:greenyellow; border-width: 4px]{a+b}$

**IMPORTANT:** If you specify a border around the math, in order for the MathJax to render correctly you **MUST** supply ***at minimum*** both the `border-style` and `border-width` properties. Further, the `border-width` property must be specified as a pixel value (e.g., `4px`). If you omit `border-style`, no border will be drawn.  If you omit `border-width` or supply it as a relative-size keyword (e.g., `thick`), the text will be misaligned to the box and, on some browsers, will mess up the alignment of all following MathJax on the page!

**ADDENDUM:** From DavideCervone's comment:

> Note that it is easier to give the combined version for borders, e.g., `border: 4px solid greenyellow` rather than giving each part separately. Finally, you can give the width in values other than pixels (e.g., `2em` or `3mm`), but you are correct that it must be an explicit width, not a keyword like `thick` in order for MathJax to be able to compensate for it properly.

Comment: The alignment issue is expected behavior. MathJax does not "know" about the 5px border in its internal process (it just passes it along) and thus does not take it into account during layout. That kind of compatibility with CSS is very hard to achieve but a long term goal for us.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Hmm. Sounds like `\fcolorbox` is for now the best way to put a colored border around some text, then?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I think I discovered a fix -- explicitly specifying a value for `border-width` appears to fix the problem in Chrome.

Comment: In Firefox, too. This is good.

Comment: A couple of comments.  MathJax *does* know about the border width that you give.  It does scan the list of attributes for some specific ones that it knows how to handle (and will compensate for the width in its calculations).  Note that it is easier to give the combined version for borders, e.g., `border: 4px solid greenyellow` rather than giving each part separately.  Finally, you can give the width in values other than pixels (e.g., `2em` or `3mm`), but you are correct that it must be an explicit width, not a keyword like `thick` in order for MathJax to be able to compensate for it properly.

Comment: In terms of arbitrary CSS, you are right, it can be passed on, but you should only use CSS that doesn't change the size of the element (other than `padding` and `border` styles).  If you change the size or position, MathJax won't know that you have done so and the spacing can get messed up, as you have seen.  Still, some interesting effects can be achieved.  For example, try `\bbox[transform:scalex(-1);display:inline-block]{a+b}` for some fun.