# The new reputation sum in the new top bar is calculated incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I was very happy when I saw a sum of new reputation of 123, thinking I may have won a bounty or something and looking forward to another epic day. Then I opened the menu and saw this:

[image: Incorrect sum shown in the reputation change dropdown icon]

I don’t know where the additional 1 came from but it was bugging to only see +23 reputation rather than the expected +123 reputation. It would be great if this bug were fixed.

Comment: A Venn diagram: $$\require{enclose}\enclose{box}{\enclose{circle}{\,\\\,\\\,\,\,\text{People who understand} \\ \,\,\,\text{what 0.023 krep means}\,\,\, \,\\} \enclose{}{\text{Most people} \\ \text{seeing this post}} \\\quad\quad \enclose{circle}{\,\\\,\\\,\,\,\text{People who can fix this bug}\,\,\, \,\\\,}}$$ Seriously though, I think you might be better off posting on meta.se. You *probably* get a faster response. Worst case scenario, it gets closed as a dupe and you find out from the linked post what's happening. At least, that's what I'd personally do if I were you.

Comment: Did you get the association bonus on any sites?

Comment: @jonsca The association bonus would show up, though.

Comment: @orthocresol Yeah, fixed, just wanted to have fun a little.

Comment: However dis- or favourable you are looking at the new top bar, it came to the whole network. As such it is an issue that should be addressed at [meta.se], not here. I did a [quick check](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D+created%3A1m..+duplicate%3A0+%5Btop-bar%5D) on the bug reports of the last month and could not find anything similar.

Comment: This has been fixed - details [are here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357705/1583).

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Whether or not this is a network-wide issue, I am pretty sure that the site meta is *also* the correct place to post this. Not everybody has or wants to join meta, yet this could be an issue to them. Along the same lines we have a local version of the [meta-tag:support] pages, if you wish.

Comment: Furthermore, I recalled that it was being rolled out stepwise, so I thought maybe not all sites had this yet …

Comment: I'm sorry I care about the rest of the network. Apparently you are right, this can be dealt with on the site meta - see, I even gave this an up-vote.

Comment: @orthocresol How did you put an image in the comments?

Comment: @PrittBalagopal [Magic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3540/16683). You can right-click on it to see the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has long since been fixed. An explanation is [over on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357705) but I didn’t understand the technical details.