# How to render a square-scheme reaction using MathJax?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, formatting, chemical-formulas

I'm try to write a square-scheme reaction using MathJax. Until now I managed this one.

```
$$\begin{array}{c}
\ce{A} \quad \ce{<=>[$k_1$][$k_2$]} \quad \ce{B}\\[-1cm]
\!\scriptsize k_3 \Large\downharpoonleft\!\!\upharpoonright \scriptsize \!\!\! k_4 \qquad
  \scriptsize k_5 \Large\downharpoonleft\!\!\upharpoonright \scriptsize \!\!\! k_6 \normalsize \\[-1cm]
\ce{C} \quad \ce{<=>[$k_7$][$k_8$]} \quad \ce{D}\\
\end{array}$$
```

$$\begin{array}{c}
\ce{A} \quad \ce{<=>[$k_1$][$k_2$]} \quad \ce{B}\\[-1cm]
\!\scriptsize k_3 \Large\downharpoonleft\!\!\upharpoonright \scriptsize \!\!\! k_4 \qquad
  \scriptsize k_5 \Large\downharpoonleft\!\!\upharpoonright \scriptsize \!\!\! k_6 \normalsize \\[-1cm]
\ce{C} \quad \ce{<=>[$k_7$][$k_8$]} \quad \ce{D}\\
\end{array}$$

Is this result acceptable? Is there any other way to achieve this result?

Comment: I don't know a use case (yet), but this one looks great for what MathJax offers out of the box. For something more complex though I'd probably just use Ti*k*Z and paste the scheme as an image.

Comment: Very, very limited functionality: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3543/4945 I recommend creating a picture. With complicated MathJax constructs you never know when it breaks and how and it will add significant overhead to loading if it gets complex.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン - Unfortunately it seems that do not possible insert $\ce{<=>}$ or even $\downharpoonleft\!\upharpoonright$.

Comment: Indeed, that is true, hence the two *very* at the beginning. I noticed something different in your code: You invoke an array with three columns, but you are only using one, i.e. you are missing the `&` separator. You do not need `$$` if you use a `\begin...\end` block (there's no harm if you do).

Comment: @Martin-マーチン - My fault. It's a *type* error. Those are remnant from my previous approach.